# Need to sort a dictionary built from multiple text files - unsure how to structure function

Tags: python, function, sorting, dictionary

I have the following code:

```
import os 
import string


#(Function A) - that will take in string as input, and return a dictionary of word and word frequency.
def master_dictionary(directory):   
    filelist=[os.path.join(directory,f) for f in os.listdir(directory)]
    
    def counter(x):
    
        f = open(x, "rt")
        words = f.read().split()
        words= filter(lambda x: x.isalpha(), words)
        word_counter = dict()
    
        for word in words:
            if word in word_counter:
                word_counter[word] += 1
            else:
                word_counter[word] = 1
    
        return (word_counter)
    
        
    def sort_dictionary(counter()):
    
        remove_duplicate = []
        new_list = dict()
        for key, val in word_counter.items():
            if val not in remove_duplicate:
                remove_duplicate.append(val)
                new_list[key] = val

        
        new_list = sorted(new_list.items(), key = lambda word_counter: word_counter[1], reverse = True)
        print (f'Top 3 words in file {x}:', new_list[:3])

    
    return [counter(file) for file in filelist]

master_dictionary('medline')
```

I need to call on the return value from the counter function to the sort_dictionary function. The function needs to combine all the dictionaries from each file and the output should only be the top 3 words from that master dictionary. Unfortunately, I don't know how to structure it.

Comment: Nested functions aren't "pythonic" (and usually aren't necessary).

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several issues:

- needlessly nested functions; this causes functions to be redefined every time the function is called
- missing return values, `sort_dictionary` doesn't return anything
- syntax error, you cannot define `sort_dictionary` with a signature of `sort_dictionary(counter())`
- confusing names, i.e. calling a `dict`, `new_list`
- actual error in functionality, check below

It looks like you want to create a function that print the top 3 words of a file, for every file in a dictionary.

Your `counter` function is more or less OK:

```
def counter(x):
    f = open(x, "rt")
    words = f.read().split()
    words= filter(lambda x: x.isalpha(), words)
    word_counter = dict()
    
    for word in words:
        if word in word_counter:
            word_counter[word] += 1
        else:
            word_counter[word] = 1
    
    return (word_counter)
```

Although it could certainly be improved upon:

```
from collections import defaultdict


def word_counter(filename):
    word_count = defaultdict(int)
    with open(filename, 'rt') as f:
        for word in f.read().split():
            word_count[word] += 1
    return word_count
```

Your `sort_dictionary` function has several issues though. You're trying to find the highest word counts by inverting the dictionary and then sorting the items for which there is no duplicate. That kinda works, but isn't very clear.

However, what if there's 2 words that both occur 10 times? You don't just want to throw one out, if the next best is only 9? I.e. what if the top counts are 10, 10, and 9. I'd imagine you'd want the two 10's and any of the 9's?

Something like this works better:

```
def top_three(wc):
    return {
        w: c for c, w in
        sorted([(count, word) for word, count in wc.items()], key=lambda x: x[0])[-3:]
    }
```

And to then put it all together in a function that gets all the files in the directory and applies these functions (which is what your question was about):

```
def print_master_dictionary(dirname):
    for filename in [os.path.join(dirname, f) for f in os.listdir(dirname)]:
        print(f'Top 3 words in file {filename}:', 
              list(top_three(word_counter(filename)).keys()))
```

All together:

```
import os
from collections import defaultdict


def word_counter(filename):
    word_count = defaultdict(int)
    with open(filename, 'rt') as f:
        for word in f.read().split():
            word_count[word] += 1
    return word_count


def top_three(wc):
    return {
        w: c for c, w in
        sorted([(count, word) for word, count in wc.items()], key=lambda x: x[0])[-3:]
    }


def print_master_dictionary(dirname):
    for filename in [os.path.join(dirname, f) for f in os.listdir(dirname)]:
        print(f'Top 3 words in file {filename}:',
              list(top_three(word_counter(filename)).keys()))


print_master_dictionary('my_folder')
```

Note that the real answer here is that part `list(top_three(word_counter(filename)).keys())` I like how the renaming of the functions makes it very clear what's happening: a list of the top three keys in a word_counter dictionary for some filename.

If you prefer a bit more of a step by step look in your code:

```
def master_dictionary(dirname):
    for filename in [os.path.join(dirname, f) for f in os.listdir(dirname)]:
        wc = word_counter(filename)
        tt = top_three(wc)
        print(f'Top 3 words in file {filename}:', list(tt.keys()))
```

The main takeaway on 'how to structure` code like this:

- write functions with a well-defined function, doing one thing and doing it well
- return results that can be easily reused, without side-effects (like printing or changing globals)
- when using the function, remember that you're calling them and after execution you need to capture the returned result, either in a variable or as an argument to the next function.

Something like this: `x(y(z(1)))` causes `z(1)` to be executed first, the result is then passed to `y()`, and once `y` completes execution and returns, its result is passed to `x()`. so `z`, `y` and `x` are executed in that order, each using the result of the previous as its argument. And you'll be left with the result of the call to `x`.

Comment: Hello, I should have been more clear. The dictionary can only give unique values and are only allowed to import certain modules (os, string, random). If the dictionary has two 10s one of them has to be taken out and the next one with a unique value has to be added into the dictionary.

Comment: So if a file has 10 copies of the word 'the', 10 copies of the word 'a', 9 copies of the word 'apple' and 8 copies of the word 'banana', you expect the output "Top 3 words in file <name>: the, apple, banana", even though 'a' is more common? Note that 'collections' is a standard Python library, not an installed package - but if you're unable to use it, you already rewrote the logic in your version of that function yourself.

Comment: Regardless, I think the answer more than answers your question - if you have any remaining issues, please be specific

Comment: Also, we were only allowed to use two main functions so I nested them.